# Unable to pass query params in Link/navigate() in Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, reach-router

I am using `Link` & `navigate()` from `@reach/router` for internal navigation and when I pass query params

eg: `<Link to="/home?param=something" />` or `navigate("/home?param=something")`, it completely ignores the query params passed in the url string, as alternative I am using the `window.location` & `<a>` tag but it has performance issues for internal routing as pointed in the gatsby docs.

so I am not sure how to tackle this issue, any help would be appreciated, Thanks.